# Why the base case with no template arguments for variadic tuple is not working?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, tuples, variadic-templates

As an exercise, I'm trying to define a variadic template for a Tuple but I found that the base case with no elements is not working.

```
template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct Tuple : Tuple<Tail...>
{
  Tuple(const Head& head, const Tail&... tail)
    : Base{tail...}, m_head{head} {}

private:
  using Base = Tuple<Tail...>;
  Head m_head;
};

template <> struct Tuple<> {};
```

MSVC 2022 gives the following error:

```
C:\projects\cpp\cpp_programming_language\28_metaprogramming\variadic_tuple.cpp(12): error C2976: 'Tuple': too few template arguments
  C:\projects\cpp\cpp_programming_language\28_metaprogramming\variadic_tuple.cpp(2): note: see declaration of 'Tuple'
C:\projects\cpp\cpp_programming_language\28_metaprogramming\variadic_tuple.cpp(12): error C2913: explicit specialization; 'Tuple' is not a specialization of a class template
```

Why this does not work and how to fix it?

Comment: "This does not work" is not a problem description. What does not work? Unexpected behaviour, compiler error?

Comment: You can't have `template <> struct Tuple<> {};`.  Your primary template requires at least one template parameter, so you'll never have 0 parameters.

Comment: @273K I edited the question to include the compiler error.

Comment: @NathanOliver But if so how to define the case for the zero elements tuple?

Comment: You don't. You define the base template, with arbitrary number of parameters, as if it was a "zero elements tuple". Then your non-base case becomes a specialization for at least one parameter. Mission accomplished.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik If I define the base case as `template <typename Head> struct Tuple<Head> { Head m_head; };` than the empty tuple `Tuple<>` does not compile.

Comment: I agree, it will not compile. But I did not write "you define the base template with one parameter". I wrote "you define the base template with arbitrary number of parameters". And I also wrote "as if it was a zero elements tuple", too...

Comment: Template parameter `Head` isn't a parameter pack. So you shall explicitly specify a template argument for it in your (full) specialization.

Comment: @Morise I'm using MSVC 2022 and it does not compile.

Comment: BTW, using recursion for tuple lead to poor compile time, You might use leaves trick instead, something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54e64171da5eb361)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One correct incantation would be

```
template <typename...> struct Tuple;

template <> struct Tuple<> {};

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct Tuple<Head, Tail...> : Tuple<Tail...>
{
```

(the rest is identical to your code).

Comment: This version gives the following compiler error: `error C2504: 'Tuple<>': base class undefined`.

Comment: @bobeff Did you forget to include  `template <> struct Tuple<> {};` ?

Comment: Yes, I moved it just below the general case and now it is working.